# Spring communication with angular2

Tags: java, ajax, spring, angular

i am trying make a message module for REST WebSevice with Java,Spring and Angular 2. Now I have almost everything (inbox of received and sent messages, sending message)  but I don't know how i can send information to frontend that user has a new message.
I can check in base does the user have unread messages when user refresh component but this will be not comfortable for his. Is that any solution to send information to frontend when user has a new message ? 
Now I am reading about event emmitter on Spring but I don't know how connect backend and frontend with this.

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I'm just learning about Spring and Angular 2 and I could overlook the answer

Comment: Such a mechanism is usually implemented over WebSocket. You may try to search for stomp-ng component for Angular. Spring has the same component. You can look through this example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Thanks, I read some about this and I think that is better solution then event emmiter.

Comment: You are welcome!